# tmux mouse select and scroll at the same time?

Tags: tmux

When in copy mode in tmux, using the mouse is there a way to select text, and scroll the window up at the same time? When selecting text the buffer does not scroll up when I reach the top boundary.

I have `set-window-option -g mode-mouse on` in my `/.tmux.conf`

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258073/how-to-scroll-while-holding-shift-to-copy-in-tmux and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398716/mouse-scrolling-and-selection-in-terminal-with-tmux

Answer (score 4):

From my .tmux.conf:

```
# Using scroll 
setw -g mode-mouse on

# Sane scrolling
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

This enables the scrolling with mouse and during the selection, it can go beyond the boundaries. Just hold shift when you're selecting.

It works for me using Mint linux.

Comment: You could edit your answer for the newer versions of tmux. So it should be `setw -g mouse on`. The scrolling and selecting is working like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

To allow both mouse scroll and select on tmux 2.1 and above, `set -g mouse on` in *~/.tmux.conf* is sufficient.

As @RobisonSantos said, you should **hold *Shift* key to copy selection**.

Comment: But how can we select **and** scroll at the same time? Your suggestion I have already applied and still I am only able to select what is shown on the current window. It seems like that shift is blocking to scroll. Is there any other tip or trick too?

Comment: @PiMathCLanguage does `setw` (set-window-option) work better for you ?